# How to avoid duplicated assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, add-in

I have little issue with Word Add-In on Visual Studio. When I add reference to Publisher it see it on same namespace (Publisher and Word). Error keeps apear even if I remove reference to Publisher. Did you face such error before and know way around?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: What does the error say ?

Comment: Error 1 An assembly with the same identity 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references. c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Office.dll WordAddIn_Test

Comment: Appears on add Publisher, stays even after remove. :/

Comment: delete the contents inside the bin directory, remove and add the reference again. clean the solution and build again.

Comment: Nothing. Cleared bin and solution back to base. Error still apears.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that just Word 2007 Add-In template has some glitch. When I create class library and added both MS-Word and MS-Publisher reference it works fine.

Michael